# Android: what layout to be used for set of views with different orientation

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design layout for following requirement

```
   |-------------------------| 
   |Image |      Text View 1 |
   | view |                  |
   |-------   <  Edit Text 2>|
   |                         |
   | <Text view 2>           |
   |                         |
   | <Edit text View 2>      |
   |                         |
   |                         |
   |   |Button view|         |
   |                         |
    --------------------------
```

My attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:background="#000024">
    <TableRow android:baselineAligned="false"  android:id="@+id/tableRow1" > 

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:padding="2dip" android:src="@drawable/icon" 
        />

        <TextView android:padding="2dip" android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Trip Name"
         />

         <EditText android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                  android:layout_gravity="centre"
                   android:id="@+id/txtUserName" 
                   android:width="200px"
          />
    </TableRow> 

    <TableRow android:baselineAligned="false">

     <TextView android:padding="2dip" android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="Description"
      />
    </TableRow> 

    <TableRow android:baselineAligned="false"> 
      <EditText 
            android:layout_width="150px" android:id="@+id/tripDesc" 
            android:password="true" 
       />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:baselineAligned="false">>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/buttonSave" 
            android:text="Save" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The problem here is  is coming at extreme right and 1st Edit Text gets disappeared. Also how I add some blank spaces between 2nd Edit Text and last Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relative1">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="2dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/imgview" />

    <TextView android:padding="2dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Trip Name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgview" android:id="@+id/trip_name_txt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/relative1" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/txtUserName" android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgview"
        android:layout_below="@id/trip_name_txt" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relative2"
    android:layout_below="@id/relative1" android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <TextView android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relative3"
    android:layout_below="@id/relative2" android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <EditText android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tripDesc" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:password="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@id/relative3"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <Button android:id="@+id/buttonSave" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Save" />
</LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Prateek. I can modify this to my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `Relative layout` and it will give you the freedom to run your app in any mode with any device of resolution. Use nine png patch for more freedom of the app.

Refer these docs:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a RelativeLayout. 
It helps you defining relations between objects. 
You can use for every object the following attributes:
layout_toRightOf
layout_toLeftOf
layout_above
layout_below
etc (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html for all attributes)
In that way you the position of the objects could be described in relation of each other. 
For example

```
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/minutesLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <org.croncalc.uicomponents.MyPicker 
                    android:id="@+id/minutepicker"
            croncalc:maxnumber="60"
            croncalc:minnumber="1"
            croncalc:step="5"
            croncalc:cycle="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </org.croncalc.uicomponents.MyPicker>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/minuteslabel" 
            android:text="@string/minlabel"                 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/minutepicker">
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see the TextView has the attribute layout_toRightOf and it specifies that the TextView object must be placed on the right of the component MyPicker. 
You can also check AbsoluteLayout.

In this example i have 2 components, and as you can see the textView has an attribute android:layout_toRightOf, with that i specify the object on the left of TextView

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using tableLayout. TableLayout gives you liberty to design layout without reference to anyother view which might change, Hence I prefer it over Relative Layout. This I have added if anybody wants the layout via tablelayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1" android:background="#000024">

    <TableRow android:baselineAligned="false" android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
      <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_outline" android:id="@+id/imgview" />

       <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView android:padding="10dip" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Trip Name"
                 android:textStyle="bold" android:id="@+id/tripEdit1"
            />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
                android:layout_width="180dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

       </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:baselineAligned="false" android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
        <TextView android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Description"
             android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="15dp" />    
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:baselineAligned="false" android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
        <EditText android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:layout_width="290dp" android:id="@+id/tripDesc"
        />  
    </TableRow>

      <TableRow android:baselineAligned="false">

      <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <Button android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/save" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_span="1"
            android:onClick="saveTrip"
            >
        </Button>

        <Button android:text="Cancel"
            android:id="@+id/cancel" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="1"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:onClick="cancelTrip"
            >
        </Button>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```